# Microsoft Viva Topic Search API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-results, sharepoint-search, microsoft-viva

We are working on viva topics provided by Microsoft, we have created the topic center site, and added few topics.

We are trying to,

a) Develop a search feature where I can search for any topics added in topic center.

b) Create a search bar where we can search for topic references, and in results we will get all the content source, wherever that topic has been tagged.

We are not getting any api provided by microsoft for both of these activities. Let me know if anybody can help me with this task.